# A CREATE statement with quoted fields in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I have created a table in Oracle 10g using the following `CREATE` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE test ("id" NUMBER(35, 0) primary key, "description" VARCHAR2(250) not null);
```

The basic table structure looks like as follows.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Column Name       Data Type         Nullable     Default    Primary Key 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                NUMBER(35, 0)     No           -          1
description       VARCHAR2(250)     No           -          -
```

It should precisely be noted that the column names in this `CREATE` statement are enclosed within double quotes just for having a fun :)

After issuing this DDL statement, I issued three DML statements to add this many rows as follows.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'aaa');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'bbb');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'ccc');
```

And finally, the following `SELECT` statement was executed to verify, if those rows were inserted.

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Oracle indeed displays three rows exactly as inserted on executing this query.

---

But when I issue the following `SELECT` query,

```
SELECT id, description FROM test;
```

Oracle complains,

> ORA-00904: "DESCRIPTION": invalid identifier

The following (same) query also,

```
SELECT id FROM test;
```

fails with the error,

> ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

The same is true for the query,

```
SELECT description FROM test;
```

The only `SELECT` query with the meta character `*` works. Listing fields in the `SELECT` clause doesn't work. Capitalizing the column names in the `SELECT` clause also doesn't work.

What is the reason behind it?

<sub>Please don't just say, *Don't do this.* I'm interested in knowing the reason behind it.</sub>

Comment: Why would you ever *want* to do that? Oh and the **reason** for this behaviour is: this is how the SQL standard is defined.

Comment: I didn't give it a try but the same should be untrue on MySQL, @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: That might be true - but MySQL is not exactly known to care about the SQL standard. And it doesn't change the fact that this **is** how the SQL standard requires it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I won't say it, I'll just think it loudly.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm) clearly says that if you have quoted identifiers, you have to quote them everywhere (my italics for emphasis):

> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a **quoted identifier** or a **nonquoted identifier**.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, *then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object*.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

So you always have to do:

```
SELECT "id", "description" FROM test;
```

Which is a pain. But obviously I'm just thinking that too, not really saying it.